# What happened to "open containing folder" in search results in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

After doing a search in Windows 7, is there a way to open the containing folder that contains the file in the list?

Ok, I just saw the **open file location** option, but it opens in the same window. Is there no way to open in a new window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> when you click **Open File Location**.